# how to install swig version 4.1.0 on ubuntu 22.04 dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get

i try to install **swig 4.1.0** on a dockerfile using a `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` image.
if i use `apt-get install -y swig` it always installs swig in the version 4.0.2 instead.

But, if i try the same on a multipass vm using the exact same ubuntu version (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) it installs the correct version 4.1.0 of swig.

i also checked my sources list to make sure there is no difference there.
it is on both those list:

```
ubuntu@primary:~$ grep ^[^#] /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
```

i also checked for the packagelist if there is a different package with the specific version but there isn't. Also i mentioning again it works on the multipass with the command `apt-get install -y swig` to install the swig version 4.1.0.

Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/151304) for a similar question on Ask Ubuntu gives a lot of great details, but the long and short is that the max version for packages is locked to the Ubuntu release. You can see the version confirmed for Jammy Jellyfish listed on the [Ubuntu packages page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/swig). To be able to use swig 4.1.0 you'll either need to add a new package repository that contains that version, or try to switch Lunar Lobster 23.04 which has swig 4.1.0 available.